# Changing global tintColor does not change button colors on xamarin forms targeting iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I am trying to change the "branding color" for the iOS target of an xamaring froms app. I read that I should change the global tint color like this:

```
 UIApplication.SharedApplication.Delegate.GetWindow().TintColor = UIColor.FromRGB((nfloat)(0x0D/256.0),(nfloat)(0x77/256.0),(nfloat)(0x6E/256.0));
```

This changes the color of the buttons in the navigation bar. But it does not change the color of any other button.

Is this behavior as it is intended?
Can I somehow change the color of all buttons and all other elements using the "iOS blue"?

Comment: UIButton.Appearance.TintColor = UIColor.FromRGB((nfloat)(0x0D/256.0),(nfloat)(0x77/256.0),(nfloat)(0x6E/256.0));

Comment: @NinjaHattori Thanks. Unfortunately it does not work and I do not understand why.

Comment: you need to add appearance code in appdelegate

Comment: I have it in `public override bool AppDelegate::FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)`, and it does not work :-(